# How would I make a dns ip that redirects where sites lead

Tags: networking, dns, redirection

I'm trying to make a custom dns to where when someone visits, for example `https://example.com/` they'll be just redirected to `https://otherexamplesite/` instead

I want to be able to do this using a custom dns ip, one a user would turn on in their devices settings

I got the idea from my jailbroken Playstation which makes the help guide redirect to a jailbreak panel for easy access, I have other use cases for this though.

Comment: @mashuptwice - This is actually incorrect.  (I'll write an answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is not strictly speaking possible - ie using DNS to do website redirection of an HTTPS site.

There are 2 stages to finding (or redirecting) a website.

- A DNS lookup to convert the website into an IP address
- A web server responding on the given IP address and forwarding the site.

So, in order to do this, you need to set up BOTH of the above elements.

- To set up the DNS you need an A record or a CNAME to a webserver capable of doing the redirection.  Very often this would be the target website.  **You can't use a CNAME for this purpose** (on the apex of the domain as per your example) as it breaks spec and will not work as you may expect.   You need to use an A record to point to the A record of the web server [ there are non standard domain features like ALIAS and ANAME records you might be able to use, and for IP6 you could use an AAAA record ]
- You then need to get the web server to answer for the domain and redirect the site.  There are a miriad of ways of doing this, and the exact howto depends on the webserver.    A tried-and-true method is to have the web server answer for all the relevant domains in the same container [ and have a single HTTPS certificate covering all the domains - Letsencrypt will allow you to generate this ], and then either do a conditional Rewrite in the web server configuration or in the web application itself.   The rewrite would typically be a 301 redirect, although there are other ways of doing this.

For the sake of clarity, there is no "DNS ONLY" way of doing it - Web servers do not recognise srv or txt records.

**THE DIFFICULTY YOU MAY HAVE WILL BE TO GET A VALID HTTPS CERTIFICATE IF YOU DO NOT OWN THE DOMAIN NAME TO REDIRECT**  To do this you would need to accept a self signed cert, or a more complex version of the same thing - ie run your own CA and install a root cert in your device/browser**

I comment that if you just want to have a device resolve to a different IP address then it normally would, most devices have a hosts file - however it may be easier to run your own recursive DNS server which provides an alternative answer to the authorative one when queried.